# Typescript best approach to parse response in model

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, model

Iam using a **API** which does return infos about my smarthome devices.
I want to parse a list of lights provided by this **API**. 
For this i created a `model` in my angular application which should resemble the response:

```ts
export class LightsModel {
  public lightModel: LightModel
}
export class LightModel {
  public state: StateModel;
}
export class StateModel {
  public on: boolean;
}
```

Maybe this is a overkill way to structure a model but the response is in reality very large so i like to split the model in multiple classes to operate easier later on the individual instances.

The response looks like:

```
{
  "1": {
    state: { on: true }
  },
  "2": {...},
  "3": {...}
}
```

My problem is that my model does not fit the reponse because i get a variable number of lights back so i can't use a hardcoded structure. Is there a way to dynamicly scale the model based on the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you can go about this.

Option 1: Use for...in

```
for (const lightId in myApiResponse) {
 const yourLight: LightModel = myApiResponse[lightId];
//do something here
}
```

Here's the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Option 2: Use Object.keys()

```
const keys = Object.keys(myApiResponse); // this will give you array of light ids ["1","2", etc.]
const lights = keys.map(t=> myApiResponse[t] as LightModel);
```

Here's the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

As far as defining your class, change LightsModel to this:

```
interface MyInterface {
  [lightId: string]: LightModel;
}
```

Hope this helps,
Isaac

Comment: I used the second option and it worked fine. Thank you! But one question; Whats the meaning of "t" in the t=>data[t]. What does it stand for?

Comment: You're not the first person to ask me this.  "t" is the implicit standard when working with lambda functions in C#.  Lambda functions in C# are the equivalent of arrow functions in TypeScript/Javascript.

The best way to explain it is, that t is just a variable name.  I could've easily done the following:

keys.map(key => myApiResponse[key] as LightModel);

Answer (score 1):

I might need more details, but it seems like you just need to setup `LightsModel` to support an array of `LightModel`s.

Something like:

```
export class LightsModel {
   public lightModels: LightModel[]
}
```